# Find Puppet code to retrieve user information

Tags: linux, puppet

Is there a way I can get comeplete user information using puppet code.
Like group id, id, password expiration details, etc.
May be using facter.

Comment: Puppet isn't really intended as a data-gathering tool, but you can run more-or-less any command via a [Bolt Task](https://puppet.com/docs/bolt/latest/writing_tasks_and_plans.html), so it should be possible, if you know what command(s) to run.  I think custom facts approach could also be used, but then passwords would be stored in plain text in the Puppet console, which isn't ideal.

Answer (score 2):

You can run any command using `facter` and centralize it using Puppet, so technically is possible, but is not advised (*as correctly stated by [boxdog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9529842/boxdog)*)

If you do that, the fact collected will be huge (as `.json`) and Puppet will have to store that in the DB and your performance is going to be slow down.

Think of Puppet's `facter` as the temperature for your AC. You need the `temperature` `fact` to be collected by the configuration management tool so that you can drive decision in order to turn on or off the heating. The reason you collect `facts` is **to drive configuration decisions**. In order to monitor your infrastructure you need a [System Monitoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_monitor) tool and not a [Configuration Management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_management) tool.

If you want to collect this information one time, Puppet has support for:

- [Bolt](https://puppet.com/docs/bolt/latest/bolt.html)
- MCollective (deprecated for newer versions, available on `<= 2018.1`)